# How do I merge cells that have data with blank cells in the same column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in the middle of writing a macro for Excel that will merge cells in column "A" containing titles with blank cells beneath it.

Here is an example of what I'm dealing with:[Actual Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSzLx.png)

Here is the desired result: [Actual After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQj0O.png)

So far I've managed to get my code to work, but I noticed that it will always skip over the "antivirus" section.

Here is what I got so far:

```
    'loop to merge titles with blank cells and add borders
LR = Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LR
    If Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "" And Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> "" Then
       u = i + 1
       Do While Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(u, 1).Value = "" And Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(u, 2) <> ""
            u = u + 1
        Loop
        Sheets(DataSheet).Range("A" & i & ":A" & (u - 1)).Select
        With Selection
            .Merge
            .BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
            .WrapText = True
            '.VerticalAlignment = x1VAlignTop
            '.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        End With
        Sheets(DataSheet).Range("B" & i & ":B" & (u - 1)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
        i = u + 1
    End If
    If Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 1).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
        Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 1).WrapText = True
        Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 2).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
        Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 2).WrapText = True
    End If
Next i
```

Please excuse any sloppiness with my code, I'm very new at this. I don't know what I am missing, but any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You need to give concrete examples of what your data looks like when it works, and when it doesn't work. "Sometimes it skips over cells or doesn't work" is not helpful, and basically means that to answer your question someone would need to debug it from scratch, including putting the code in a worksheet and trying to make up some data which recreates your problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick feedback. I will try to remove any personal data from my actual data and provide a real before/after example.

Comment: Great - when you respond to someone's comment, you should always type "@" and then their username. That pings that person so they know you've said something to them. After you've edited your question, if you want me to take a look at it, make a comment that includes @Grade and press Tab to make the site type out my whole username.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - Thank you! I just finished editing with better before/after pictures to better show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your initial If statement, as follows:

```
If Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "" And Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> "" Then
```

In English, this says, "If the current row is NOT blank, and the next row IS blank, and the 3rd row is NOT blank, then..."

But you can see that both of cells A55 & A56 are blank, following A54 which says "Anti-Virus". So, you've failed the test that you set for yourself, and it ignores this section. If you want it to work for this section, you will need to code it to actually count how many blank cells there are in a row, following a non-blank cell. That will tell you how many to merge together.

Comment: Hmm I will take a look at my opening "If" statement for the loop. My goal was for it to check if the cell beneath was empty, but also if the cell down one row in column B has data. This way the loop would stop naturally once it reaches the last cell in column A. Maybe I am going about this entirely wrong? Either way thank you for the help!

Comment: The way I read your workbook, it already knows the last row, based on how you've defined LR. So instead, you could just check to see whether you're below that point. ie: if LR is 70, and your loop is at A69, and you want to see whether you're below the bottom of your data loop, you could stop at checking A69 + 1 more row.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! 
Both "if" statements were working for certain portions when they should have been exclusive, so I changed the second "if" statement to an "else". I also found that when I was setting "i = u" I forgot to take into account that "next i" would increase "i" once more than I needed, so I changed that to "i = u - 1" to compensate.

Here is the code:

```
'This is the section that I'm having trouble with!
'loop to merge titles with blank cells and add borders
LR = Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LR
    If Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "" And i <> LR Then
       u = i + 1
       Do While Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(u, 1).Value = "" And Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(u, 2) <> ""
            u = u + 1
        Loop
        Sheets(DataSheet).Range("A" & i & ":A" & (u - 1)).Select
        With Selection
            .Merge
            .BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
            .WrapText = True
            '.VerticalAlignment = x1VAlignTop
            '.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        End With
        Sheets(DataSheet).Range("B" & i & ":B" & (u - 1)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
        i = u - 1
    Else
        Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 1).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
        Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 1).WrapText = True
        Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 2).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
        Sheets(DataSheet).Cells(i, 2).WrapText = True
    End If
Next i
```